CLOSED_ACCOUNT_DISCRIMINATOR removed from 0.30
In Anchor 0.29 I was manually closing out accounts in my contract like this.
let item_account_info = ctx.accounts.item.to_account_info();
let mut data = item_account_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
for byte in data.deref_mut().iter_mut() {
    *byte = 0;
}
let item_dst: &mut [u8] = &mut data;
let mut item_cursor = Cursor::new(item_dst);
item_cursor.write_all(&CLOSED_ACCOUNT_DISCRIMINATOR).unwrap();

Now I upgraded to 0.30, this is no longer possible so I'm trying to find some documentation on what is the most secure way to close an account within the program.

I was able to solve this by using the recommended method of passing the close attribute.
#[account(mut, close = destination)]

https://github.com/coral-xyz/sealevel-attacks/blob/master/programs/9-closing-accounts/recommended/src/lib.rs
However, I'm still wondering if there are still other secure ways to close an account inline in program contract without passing the attribute.
